# Why is .on('change', handler) not working in chromium, but .change() does?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, rspec, chromium

I have struggled with rspec tests using selenium driver with very freaking simple code

```
$('div#filter').on('change', 'input, select', () => {
    alert('hello !');
});
```

Obviously i have a div#filter with multiple inputs and selecboxes. When i use this code in development with my Chrome browser( latest version ), alert fires.

But my tests were failing. Then i switch to selenium_chrome driver out of desperation ( i had to install chrome-driver). It fails as well. Then i turned on chromium my self, accessed the webpage and it really didn't work. I changed it to .change method, and it worked O_o.

What am i missing here? Everything works on classic chrome.

Another thing, if i use

```
$(document).on('change', 'div#filter input, div#filter select', () => {
```

It works in chromium as well ...

Comment: Sounds to me like `div id=filter` doesn't exist at the time you run the first block. What does `$('div#filter').length` return when you run it?

Comment: it is there, i can see it on screenshot

Comment: Seeing it can be very different than it existing at the time you query the dom for it. If it is inserted after that block runs nothing is found to attach the listener to. The second block uses event delegation which accounts for elements added in the future after it runs

Comment: i checked it, expect(page) to have_selector div#filter, count: 1 is passing

Comment: try to add event in document ready

Comment: @NegiRox not working as well, weird right ? i think i have tried that already, but i gave another go, no luck - There i am standing and saying to myself that i though i new jquery pretty well :D